# VC dimension of standard topology on the reals

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Can there be an uncountable set $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that for each subset $D\subseteq S$, there is an open set $U$ with $D=S\cap U$?

I'm asking merely out of curiosity, but I'll mention that this would imply $2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: You are asking whether the real line has an uncountable discrete subspace. The answer is no, because the real line is a separable metric space, and every subspace is separable and second countable.

Comment: See also a more interesting question replacing open by Borel sets: https://mathoverflow.net/q/403888/4600

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An uncountable $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has an accumulation point $x\in S$. Then for $D=\{x\}$ there is no such open set $U$.

Comment: Nice... I should have tried harder but hopefully you enjoyed writing that :)