# VC dimension of Borel sets

Tags: set-theory, borel-sets

Can there be an uncountable set $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that for each subset $D\subseteq S$, there is a Borel set $U$ with $D=S\cap U$?

I'm asking merely out of curiosity, but I'll mention that this would imply $2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0}$. This is a hopefully more interesting adaption of a recent [too easy question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/403870/4600).

Comment: FYI, $2^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_0}$ is sometimes called [*Lusin's second continuum hypothesis*](https://www.google.com/search?q=Luzin+%22second+continuum+hypothesis%22&filter=0) or [*Lusin's hypothesis*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lusin%27s+hypothesis%22&filter=0).

Comment: Duplicate here: [Does there exist an uncountable separable metric space $X$ such that every subset of $X$ is a Borel set?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155522/does-there-exist-an-uncountable-separable-metric-space-x-such-that-every-subse)

Comment: @Joseph ah yes, the answer is the same although the question is asking for less...

Comment: This question is originally due to Keith Ramsay.

Comment: For every uncountable complete separable metric space X, there is a bijection $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $A\subseteq X$ is Borel if and only if $f[A]$ is Borel. With this Borel equivalence in mind, we know that my old question is equivalent to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes! Martin's Axiom implies that if $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $|S| < \mathfrak{c}$, then every subset $D$ of $S$ is a relative $G_\delta$ in $S$: i.e., there is a $G_\delta$ set $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $X \cap S = D$. (And let me note that $2^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_1}$ is another consequence of Martin's Axiom.)

Comment: Nice, this applies to Kathleen Romanik's testing dimension as well.